# Html5 css3 Jquery Page Transition

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, transition

Im trying to make a web site like this.

http://www.moonrisekingdom.it

And im quite new on making html - jquery - php complex websites... Im used to as3 but i have to do this html.

Can you help to figure out how it works in general terms?

I looked into source codes and saw they when you click button, loader div appends and content loades in it and slide transition happens. Which one Jquery or css3 transition should i use for it? And how can i load content like this? Ajax may be?

Thanks for guiding

Yudum

Comment: Sorry @user1800230, this is a Q&A site for programming questions. You question is just to vague to give any useful help. If you do have a specific problem, please ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are using **jQuery** you will be fine.

It offers enough features to accomplish a website like the one you mentioned.

You can load content via ajax as you mentioned which is included in **jQuery**:

**jQuery .ajax() Documentation**

[jQuery .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

All the fancy "**sliding**" stuff is also done with jQuery:

[jQuery slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

[jQuery slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

[jquery Show&Hide Effect](http://jqueryui.com/show/)

When it comes to sliding & hiding in different directions, you could take a look at the effect *slide*. Which you can tell to slide in from the left, hide to the right, slide in from up and hide from up.

Go take a look at it, nobody will provide you the solution to the website you like to create, come back with a problem or a piece of code and everybody will be pleased to help you, but SO is no code factory or whatsoever, if you would like to have something like this contact a freelancer.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much. I will focus on these.